# Kairos API - gallery_name is not a valid parameter

Tags: python, python-3.x, face-detection, kairos-api

I'm trying to face detection using [kairos](https://kairos.docs.apiary.io/#reference/face-recognition) API. I have a following python code. But, I'm getting an error :

```
img1.jpg
================RESPONSE=====================
b'{\n\t"Errors": [\n\t\t{\n\t\t\t"ErrCode": 1003,\n\t\t\t"Message": "gallery_name is not a valid parameter"\n\t\t},\n\t\t{\n\t\t\t"ErrCode": 1003,\n\t\t\t"Message": "subject_id is not a valid parameter"\n\t\t}\n\t]\n}'
-1
```

**My code:**

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import requests
import io
import http.client
import base64
import json
import glob, os
from os.path import basename

dir_path = "/home/Photos/" 
path = "/home/Kairos/kairos_jason/"

os.chdir(dir_path)

for file in glob.glob("*.jpg"):
    img_path = file
    print(img_path)
    files = {'image': (img_path, open(dir_path + img_path, 'rb'), 'image/jpg', {'Expires': '0'})}

    headers = {
        'app_id': "My_Id",
        'app_key': "My_Key",
    }

    values_enrol = {
       "subject_id" : "11",
       "gallery_name" : "msc_galary"
    }

    res = requests.post('https://api.kairos.com/detect', headers=headers, files=files, data=values_enrol)

    print("================RESPONSE=====================")
    print(res.content)
    strRes = str(res.content)

    print(strRes.find("face_id"))
    with open(path + os.path.splitext(img_path)[0] + ".txt" , 'w') as outfile:
        outfile.write(str(res.content))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `/detect` URL doesn't accept any `gallery_name`

However, `gallery_name` is needed in the following urls:

- `/gallery/view`
- `/gallery/remove`
- `/gallery/remove_subject`
- `/gallery/view_subject`

Given that your data is also including a `subject_id`, it's clear that you need to rewrite your request towards the `/view_subject` url

`res = requests.post('https://api.kairos.com/gallery/view_subject', headers=headers, files=files, data=values_enrol)`

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.